# efficient way to extract text and title from many HTML pages

Tags: c#, html, matlab, html-agility-pack

I would like to know the efficient way to extract text from many(1000 html pages )and store each text that extracted from each page as own html page name ,

the way is to extract as possible what are those pages talking about .. 
i have been tested and seen some questions and answers .. but it would not efficient for extracted pure text,

for the following example.. there lot of information such as linkage and format codes, tags and others not in my interest.. so for this page

```
<html>
    <title>Sport today and tomorrow </title>
    <body>
           <h1> sport players.</h1>
           something....
           <h3> sport plays </h3>
           <img src="sport.jpg"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

so the extracted information are stored in text file with name of that page and contain only : 
page title = sport ... 
content = sport....

My question is there any tools or software can do that ? 
what is the name of field deal with this problem.. like DOM or some others ?

i would thank any one can give me a note regarding this issue .

My programming language is C#.. and Matlab thanks

Comment: Is there a specific pattern of content that you're looking for?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by *title and text*? Inner text of `<title>` element for *title* and inner text of any element for *text*? Merely asking for tools or software is off-topic here in StackOverflow.

Comment: Look into Anglesharp, it claimed to be [faster than HtmlAgilityPack](https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp/wiki/Performance)

Comment: After the update, I think I was right about *title*, but it is still not clear regarding *text*. Is it the text inside `h1`,`h2`, `h3`, so on.. tag?

Comment: Yes , i mean the text inside body tags which look like inside h1, h2, ..etc .. for declaring what each page speaking about ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [`AngleSharp`](https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp/wiki/Documentation), you can get title element via `IHtmlDocument.Title` and get heading elements using LINQ [`OfType<IHtmlHeadingElement>()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). The following is an example in Console Application :

```
using AngleSharp.Dom.Html;
using AngleSharp.Parser.Html;

....

var raw = @"<html>
    <title>Sport today and tomorrow </title>
    <body>
           <h1> sport players.</h1>
           something....
           <h3> sport plays </h3>
           <img src=""sport.jpg""/>
    </body>
</html>";
var parser = new HtmlParser();
var document = parser.Parse(raw);

var title = document.Title;
var headings = document.All
                       .OfType<IHtmlHeadingElement>()
                       .Select(h => h.TextContent.Trim())
                       .ToList();
Console.WriteLine(title);
Console.WriteLine();
foreach (var heading in headings)
{
    Console.WriteLine(heading);
}
```

**output :**

```
Sport today and tomorrow

sport players.
sport plays
```